# Using Resnet with keras in order to build a CNN Model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

Do we have to implement resnet algorithm in keras or it does already exist ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it already exist, which is faster to use the pretrained ResNet models in Keras. Keras has many of these backbone models with their Imagenet weights available in its [library](https://keras.io/applications/).

Refer [this](https://keras.io/applications/#resnet) documentation directly to better understand the resnet application in Keras - https://keras.io/applications/#resnet

Comment: Cool , do you have any example how to integrate it in my model in order to build the cnn model on my dataset?

Comment: Here you go - https://keras.io/applications/ you will find very first application - Classify ImageNet classes with ResNet50